# Spring boot disable SAML security in Local environment

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, saml, spring-saml

I am using spring boot 1.4.0+spring-security-saml2-core 1.0.2 with the help of following link [Spring-Boot-Saml-example](https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample) it is working great. Now i would like to disable the spring-saml security in my local environment(Local PC).It should work in DEV & Production environment.What is the minimal change i should do to disable the SAML security in spring-Boot? or is it possible to set default user who is having all the securities so that SAML won't do the security checks(This is my assumption).

Comment: It would be great at least some one provide a hint to resolve this issue.

Comment: not sure if you've seen this: https://github.com/ulisesbocchio/spring-boot-security-saml but eases integration between spring boot and spring-security-saml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to accomplish this is to use [Spring Profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html).  You can setup a local profile that uses basic authentication and then enable SAML in your higher environments.

[Profile Tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-profiles-example/)

[Disable Spring Security using profiles](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.while gone through the link it seems it will resolve my problem.In the application.properties file i will set following property spring.profiles.active=local(For dev it will be dev) and in the WebSecurityConfig.java i will set @Profile("dev") so that SAML configuration will be run for Dev environment instead of local right?I hope those informations are sufficient also i have environment spcific property file so i can flip it easily.Let me know for any more changes

Comment: It is working great.Thank a lot for the shared links.

Comment: Is it possible to include a dummy user in SAML security context? Because currently if the profile is "local" SAML itself not getting excuted instead i want to run SAML with dummy(HardCoded) user if the profile is local or have a create SAML session with dummy user.Is it possible?I am also ok to create new stack overflow question.

Comment: Yes, this should be possible.  I would recommend opening a new question for it where you include code from your SamlUserDetail Service.  This is a matter of creating an in memory user with the same granted authorities that the SAML user is issued.

Comment: Thank you.Let me create it now.

Comment: I have created following stack overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38592343/how-to-create-an-in-memory-user-in-saml to create an in memory user with the same granted authorities that the SAML user is issued.